# How do you return from a Meteor.methods stub in Cucumber

Tags: meteor, cucumber, meteor-velocity

I have just begun using Cucumber (xolvio:cucumber@0.20.2_1) with Meteor to test my project, and I am having difficulty returning a value from a Meteor.methods stub I created within a step definition.

**register-user.js**

```
this.When(/^he clicks the verification link in his email$/, function () {
        console.log(this.server.call('_getUser'));
});
```

**registration.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    _getUser: function() {
        return Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': 'anyemail@email.com'});
});
```

The log outputs a huge object that looks like the state of the system.  I noticed elsewhere that someone suggested

```
this.server.call('aMethod').then(function(response) {

    // you can use the response here

});
```

But when I do this in my project, cucumber logs `Object [object Object] has no method 'then'`.

I also tried `Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': anemail@email.com});` within the step definition, but I am receiving the error `Meteor is not defined`

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I realized that when I was logging a huge object, it was because the Meteor method `_getUser` wasn't returning anything.  I then tried `Meteor.users.find({}).fetch()` and it returned an empty array, even though my meteor-cucumber collection had my user there, which is another issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: I was fighting this exact same issue late last night (testing the verification link). Firstly as of some recent version cucumber no longer returns *promises* which is why `.then()` doesn't work anymore. xolvio says we should use `browser.executeAsync()` to fire server methods. There's discussion [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/the-right-way-to-handle-authentication-and-authorization-in-cucumber-for-meteor/2926/4). I haven't figured out the proper way to do this yet so I'm looking forward to someone answering in detail.

Comment: Interesting.  I guess I can rule out that solution.  Thanks.

According to this article: http://joshowens.me/cucumber-js-and-meteor-the-why-and-how-of-it/ it is bad to check and assert against the database because end-to-end tests are from the perspective of the user. They have no knowledge and should have no knowledge of the DB.  This type of testing would better be solved by integration or unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `this` or `then`, the latest version of Chimp is synchronous, so you just do this:

`var user = server.call('_getUser')`

Just be sure to have `registration.js` as part of your Meteor app and not part of the test codebase.

Comment: So if we need server fixtures for cucumber we need to pollute the actual app with them? Presumably we can at least guard them based on the environment the app is running in?

Comment: Although I guess I could put the server fixtures in the debug-only testing package.

Comment: Yes, a fixture package with debugOnly is the way to go, you can also put files you want to be copied into the Meteor app under `/tests/cucumber/fixtures/my-fixture.js`

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because my method was acting synchronously all the time, it just couldn't find my user so it gave me an odd result instead. My ``registration.js`` is part of the test codebase though, at ``/tests/cucumber/fixtures/registration.js``.  I haven't rebuilt my app with comparable methods yet, so I can't test those specific ones and had to build my own to make end-to-end tests.  Why would my fixtures folder be copied over to my Meteor app?

Comment: It's how xolvio:cucumber works :) Anything you put in the `/fixtures` folder is copied into the mirror only, but not the main app. I would not use this folder at all and instead use the fixture package pattern like this: https://meteor-testing.readme.io/docs/data-fixtures

Comment: Good to know, I'll be looking into this.  Thanks!