# Stub a Meteor Method in Cucumber?

Tags: meteor, cucumber, meteor-velocity

I would like to stub a Meteor method in Cucumber (using Velocity) so that when the Scenario runs and a button is clicked, I do not want it to send an email like it normally would.

My fixtures file in `/tests/cucumber/fixtures/fixture.js` contains a Meteor.method with the same name as a Meteor.method in the actual app.  Of course, this prevents Meteor from running because Method names need to be unique.

I did notice the `stubMethod()` function here: https://meteor-testing.readme.io/docs/velocity-helpers, but this is marked as a Jasmine-only function.

How can I stub a Meteor method in Cucumber?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can use [xolvio:email-stub](https://atmospherejs.com/xolvio/email-stub) to stub `Email`. If you look through the [source code](https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-email-stub/) you can see how the stub is built. Note that the docs on GH are a bit out of date, the method names are wrong. You can get the right ones from the [code](https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-email-stub/blob/master/email.js).

Comment: Excellent, this worked, thank you.  I added the package and then called ``server.call('emailStub/stub');`` in the step definition right before the email would be sent and it intercepted it properly.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome! I was just struggling with this the other night. You might also find [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760737/how-do-you-return-from-a-meteor-methods-stub-in-cucumber/33767848?noredirect=1#comment55316722_33767848) useful