# Chimpjs and Meteor: method calls in tests without using Velocity

Tags: meteor, cucumber, cucumberjs, meteor-velocity

This app shows an example of testing Meteor with Cucumber:
https://github.com/mhurwi/cucumber-meteor-tutorial

It works well with Velocity. But my computer becomes very slow when starting an app with Velocity and I don't want it to always run when I'm developing. So I tried to use Chimp as an NPM module by using

```
chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000
```

as proposed here:
https://chimp.readme.io/docs/getting-started-with-meteor-cucumber

But the tests with method calls (the methods are in tests/cucumber/fixtures/) don't work:

```
Error: Method not found [404]
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I should do in order to run the Cucumber tests using the command line instead of Velocity?

Thank you for your help.

Another small question: does Velocity take a lot of time when it's the first launch (I only have a few tests and it nearly freezes my computer) or is it the same every time?

Comment: See Xolvio's [answer and dialogue under that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760737/how-do-you-return-from-a-meteor-methods-stub-in-cucumber/33767848?noredirect=1#comment55316722_33767848). He specifically says to put the fixtures in `/fixtures`

Comment: My files are in tests/cucumber/fixtures. Isn't that alright?

Comment: Seems he meant at the root level. The other approach is to put the methods in a debug only package which is what I've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running Chimp against Meteor, you can't put fixtures in `tests/cucumber/fixtures`, you have to use the fixture package pattern, see here:

https://meteor-testing.readme.io/docs/data-fixtures

Then you can call the fixtures using `server.call('xxx')` from your step defs

Comment: I still seem to be having issues using this package pattern wrapper if you have any suggestions (detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303443/meteor-js-using-server-call-when-testing-with-chimp)